# [WinError 2]: Can't install pyodbc on Windows Server

Tags: python, pip, windows-server-2012, pyodbc

I'm using python 3.5 on windows server 2012 in azure. I'm not able to install pyodbc. Any ideas?

```
C:\Users\x>pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-3.0.10.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc
    Complete output from command c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\pyt
ip-3cwce_9k-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Did you open the command prompt as Administrator ("Command Prompt (Admin)") before trying the above?

Comment: Yes. But thankfully I was able to install pyodbc on python 3.4.3 -
not sure why it didn't work for 3.5 though.